# NSPopUpButton selection to Float Swift 4

Tags: swift, floating-point, iboutlet, nspopupbutton

I am trying to get a `String` value to a `Float` value from a `NSPopUpButton`.

E.g. I have 3 number selections. 50, 20, 10. When the user selects one of the numbers I would like a calculation made into a `Float` value.

I know this may be something very simple but I am new and I can't find anything on Stackoverflow. Any help would be appreciated. Here is an example of the code I have.

```
@IBOutlet weak var userInput: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var result: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userMenuSelection: NSPopUpButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    userMenuSelection.removeAllItems()
    userMenuSelection.addItems(withTitles: ["50", "20", "10"])
}

@IBAction func pushButtonforResult(_ sender: Any) {
    /* 
    Not sure how to take the selected userMenuSelection and multiply it by the users input to get my result in a float. 
    E.g. look below. This of course does not work because the menu items are strings. 
    */

    result.floatValue = userMenuSelection * userInput.floatValue
}
```

Hope this makes sense to what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let arr = ["50", "20", "10"]
```

//

```
@IBAction func pushButtonforResult(_ sender: NSPopUpButton) {
   let selectedValue = Float(arr[sender.selectedTag()])!
   Result.floatValue = selectedValue * userInput.floatValue

   // OR

    let selectedValue = Float(sender.selectedItem!.title)!
    result.floatValue = selectedValue * userInput.floatValue

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I tried both those options but they do not work in my code. Also "let" can't be used when userMenuSelection is an @IBoutlet.  Any ideas?

Comment: try edit ......... also don't start a variable name with capital letter

Comment: I think its getting closer to working but still getting an error.  This is the error: Value of type 'Any' has no member 'selectedTag'  Cast 'Any' to 'AnyObject' or use 'as!' to force downcast to a more specific type to access members.

Comment: convert the sender parameter from **Any** to **NSPopUpButton**

Comment: ah yes that makes sense. Ok now there is another error message. its highlighting the result variable and says: Value of type 'NSTextField' has no member 'floatvalue'

Comment: Its working now. I really appreciate you taking the time. I learned a lot :)

Comment: If you don't set the tags then use `indexOfSelectedItem` instead of `selectedTag()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, your `userMenuSelection` has titles representing the Float values as String.

You can simply retrieve the selected title and convert it to `Float`:

```
@IBAction func pushButtonforResult(_ sender: Any) {
    var selectedValue = Float(userMenuSelection.titleOfSelectedItem ?? "0") ?? 0.0

    result.floatValue = selectedValue * userInput.floatValue
}
```